# Logical operator AND/ OR short circus in Javascript

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, short-circuit-evaluation

Im still in very basic phase of JS,encountered a exercise I stucked recently, here's the code below:

```
alert(alert(0) || alert(2));
```

result return as 0 , then 2 and undefined

I understand how the OR work as looking for truthy value first, return the last value if none are found, but in code above, isn't it should stop evaluation after 2? Why the undefined return as well? It is falsy value.

Comment: `alert` itself has no return value, so it just produces `undefined`. You evaluate `undefined || undefined`

Comment: The message popup is a side effect of calling `alert`, it has nothing to do with the value those expressions return.

Answer (score 2):

> result return as 0 , then 2 and undefined

It sounds like you incorrectly assume that the value displayed is also returned from the `alert()` function. This is not so. `alert()` always returns `undefined`. The first alert **displays** `0`, but `0` is not returned. Rather the `alert()` function returns the value `undefined`. Since this is "falsey", `alert(2)` is also called which **displays** a `2` then returns `undefined` which is the final result of the `||` operator. Then this "undefined" is shown by the final alert.